# hadoop version 2 (YARN) execution scenario outcome?

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

Suppose we have 5 container in our YARN system. We have two jobs to run. Job1 has 8 Map tasks and 2 Reduce tasks. Job2 have 4 Map and 1 reduce task.
How will the YARN system decide to run which tasks first?
and How many mapper and reducers will start concurrently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How will the YARN system decide to run which "tasks" first?**
It is a map reduce job. So map tasks are executed first. Now the order (i guess that this is your real question), of execution of the jobs depends on the scheduler used. fifo uses first in first out - this is not used anymore in production environments since we have options such as capacity and fair scheduler. This is a broad topic again. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/FairScheduler.html https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html The execution also depends on the cluster resources available at the time of submitting the jobs.

**How many mapper and reducers will start concurrently?**
Reducers (at least the reduce method) will be executed only after
all the map tasks are completed. You have mentioned about the number of containers but not the number of nodes.
Concurrent execution depends on the memory you allocate to the map and reduce tasks. Take a look at these properties: yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb, yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb, yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb, mapreduce.map.memory.mb, mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb.

**Update 1:** Shuffle and sort will start the moment one of the map tasks is completed. This means while the other map tasks are still being executed, the partitioned (and combined data if at all a combiner is run) mapper output will be transferred to the reducer. But reduce method will be called only after this transfer procedure is done (for all map tasks after they are completed). Yes, container allocation would have happened by then.

Comment: my concern is about the shuffling of the intermediate data in the background

Comment: whether it will assign any container to the reduce tasks or it will wait for the mapppers to finish first. becasue it is mention that the reduce task start after 5% of map tasks completed

Comment: where can i get the complete information about the Update1 mentioned in your answer? Marco99

Comment: Though there are various sources available, I would recommend 'Hadoop - The definitive guide' by Tom White (4th edition).